# Show Popup only once when an activity in started the second time in a row

Tags: android, android-activity, popup, android-preferences

I want a popup to be shown only when a activity in launching the second time. Once the popup is shown, it should never appear again. Can anyone give a sample on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when user run application first time Store some value in SharedPreference, Get that value every time if it is present then show your pop up and delete shared preference value.

Comment: Thank you. But i want to show the popup only the second time when an activity is started

Comment: thats why i told to delete preference value after showing your popup whenever you get it.

Comment: save 1 in pref for first time and add 1 to this value every time app is launched. If pref value is 2, then show popup else not.

Comment: Thank you @seema. I will try your idea. But will there be a problem if the preference keeps on adding 1 to it every time on launch. Memory will be consumed right?

Comment: delete the value if pref is 2.

Comment: Delete pref after showing dialog. Then you will have to check if pref exists and if its value is 2.